# ASP.NET Trying to create buttons dynamically with ASP Button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I was trying to create "asp:buttons" dynamically with special asp tags (<%%>) as I am using a loop in the codebehind to generate x amount of buttons based on the database. However, when the special tag tries to write out the asp button, the button does not work.

I know that the problem is due to it not converting when it's being written out.

For example, when I view source an asp button is suppose to look like this:

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1" value="Hello" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" class="button" style="color:White;background-color:Transparent;border-style:None;" />`

but the asp button being written on the view source was shown as:

`<asp:Button ID='Button1' CssClass='button' BackColor='Transparent' runat='server' BorderStyle='None' ForeColor='white' Text='Hello' OnCommand='Button1_Click' CommandArgument='cat0002' />`

If there are other ways to create the buttons please do recommend me too as I have to create them dynamically while trying to display them in the individual table data I created. And I would need to pass the values through to the code behind as I have to call the SQL database when its clicked.

Comment: You can use `Button` constructor like `new Button() { ID = "buttonID", Text = "ButtonText" }` and then put `button.Click += (sender, e) { // click event here }`. Don't forget to add button control into the form afterwards with `FormName.Controls.Add`.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
protected void Page_Load()

    {
      Button ButtonChange = new Button();

      ButtonChange.Text = "New Button";
      ButtonChange.ID = "btnNew_" + i.ToString();
      ButtonChange.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(7);
      ButtonChange.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
      ButtonChange.Click += new EventHandler(test);
    }
```

more info :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx